# How is `if (!integer) {}` evaluated?

Tags: php

I came across this code in a php database class:

```
if( !$this->_Link_ID )
```

`Link_ID` is an integer.

So does this code just check if `Link_ID` is not `0`?

I know from experience that if a variable is type Boolean, you can just test the var like

```
$myBoolean = true;
if ($myBoolean){
    // code
}
```

I didn't realise this can be done for integers.

So how is `if( !$this->_Link_ID )` evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It checks if the integer is zero if it's integer. It also evaluates to truth if it's set to null and if it's unset, but in the latter case it also spits out a warning. if there was no negation, that would be a test for non-zero.

For more details see: [converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

Answer (score 1):

this is simply a silly way of check for non-zero,if LINK_ID is 0 or null or false ,it will

give true(please notice the '!') ,else if the LINK_iD is any thing it will give false

> > LINK_iD = 1   ,if (!LINK_ID) //this will give false
>
> LINK_ID = 0  if (!LINK_iD) //this will give true

Comment: it really error-prone to use ! cuz it will give inverted results better use `isset()` if you want to check if set,or use the == to see if equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !$this->_Link_ID )
```

will return true if the value of $this->_Link_ID is 0, empty string or null.

If you want to check explicitly for "0" then you should use the triple equal ("===" or "!==") to test the value. like so

```
if($this->_Link_ID === 0)
```

or

```
if($this->_Link_ID === false)
```

if you only want it to return true for false, but not "0".

Answer (score 0):

`if (!$this->_Link_ID)` will be true if `$this->_Link_ID` is not 0, and false if it is 0.

In PHP, you can test anything as a Boolean. A Boolean can be represented as 0 or 1, with 0 being false and 1 being true. In PHP, anything that is not 0 will be true, and anything that is 0 will be false. For example:

```
$string = 'This is a test.'

if ($string) echo 'Evaluated to true!';
```

Will print 'Evaluated to true!'. If `$string` does not exist, it will print nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
if (!is_int($var))
```

because

```
if (!$var)
```

checks if $var is not 0 or false

and if you want to check if `$var` exists you need to use this:

```
if (isset($var))
```

Answer (score 0):

not only integers though

Here goes an explanation http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php
And here goes a cheat-sheet http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php